# How can I use case classes with slicks TSQL interpolator?

Tags: scala, slick

The `sql` interporlator allows case classes as a result given a GetResult instance

```
val action:DBIO[Seq[VisibilityRow]] = sql"SELECT * FROM visibility".as[VisibilityRow] //compiles fine
```

[Checking the docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#type-checked-sql-statements), I don't see an example of utilizing `tsql` along with a case class.

I decided to just try it out

```
val action2:DBIO[Seq[VisibilityRow]] = tsql"SELECT * FROM visibility"
```

However I am getting errors

```
[error] ... : type mismatch;
[error]  found   : slick.profile.SqlStreamingAction[Vector[(Long, String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp)],(Long, String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp),slick.dbio.Effect]
[error]  required: slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api.DBIO[Seq[com.fevo.slick.Schema.VisibilityRow]]
[error]     (which expands to)  slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Seq[com.fevo.slick.Schema.VisibilityRow],slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.All]
[error]     val action2:DBIO[Seq[VisibilityRow]] = tsql"SELECT * FROM visibility"
```

Is there an elegant way for me to extract these types using `tsql`, I could map over the apply but then I still need to specify (and update) the tuple type for `DBIO`'s parameter accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence. You should be able to do: `tsql"SELECT * FROM visibility".map(_.map(VisibilityRow.apply.tupled))`. I think you're saying you don't want that?

Comment: Yeah its my misunderstanding, i thought for the macro to succeed I needed to specify the types, I now realize (trying your code) thats not true. If you like you can turn this into an answer and ill accept.
Since my case classes have options (some fields aren't required) I can't directly map over apply, but that's probably a whole new question.

Comment: Answer added. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the case class constructor matches your fields, you can simply map over the result to get the type you need:

```
val action2:DBIO[Seq[VisibilityRow]] = 
  tsql"SELECT * FROM visibility".map(_.map(VisibilityRow.apply.tupled))
```